# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to pass

```
ObjectId obj_id = new ObjectId("8cb2010d27e13509d364436256e972c0");
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("zones.$id").is(obj_id));
```

but I am getting an exception

```
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [8cb2010d27e13509d364436256e972c0]`
```

but when I am passing same Hexa value from my mongo shell I am getting my output.I am not able to understand what went wrong.Can anyone help me?

And also I want to know is there any easy way to query objects with DBRef in mongo document using spring

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), `ObjectId` takes a 12-byte hex string as a parameter, yours is 16 byte -> too large.

Comment: please read above question properly,as i said when i am using same hex value in mongo shell i am getting my output.How

Comment: Maybe mongo shell is more lenient when parsing the input and accepts only the first 12 bytes? Have you checked that the input you passed in is really the same when you try to output it?

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of [ObjectId.isValid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java#L90) - it checks that the string is 24 chars long.

Comment: may be you can share a screenshot where it worked in mongo shell and what version are you on ? Looks like there is validation in the mongo shell(3.2) too.I'm just curious.

Comment: @radoh i have checked it is the same input i passed when i am trying to output it